# Capturing mouse/keyboard events outside of form (app running in background)

Tags: c#, keyboard, background, mouse, capture

I have an app that runs in the background (minimized/task tray). I need to be able to detect mouse activity (clicks, move) as well as keyboard activity.

What is the best way to do this given the constraint that my window is not "focused" ?

Comment: and why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Doesn't really matter why. You don't have to explain motives behind asking questions here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The magic words are windows hooks. These are created with a p/invoke call to [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw). You can set up a hook to monitor, among others, keyboard and mouse events. Normally, such hooks are local to the application, but you can also create global hooks. The Microsoft KB [shows](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/318804) how.

However, be aware that not all types of global hooks can be used from .NET. In particular, there are only two that you *can* use: the **low-level** keyboard and mouse hooks, known as `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and `WH_MOUSE_LL`. Luckily, these are just what you need.

Comment: was this during the times on SO where external code samples where ok?

Comment: Probably. It's several screens of code so I prefer not to edit it in right now.

Comment: Looks like that page is gone now - can be found at [betaarchive.com](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/318804)

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at this library [globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook).
It is 100% managed c# code to install global mouse and keyboard hooks.
It wraps low level hooks into common windows forms keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: This one works great while the approach of the accepted answer did not (just returned an empty hook-handle, no errors).
Thanks for sharing it