# C# MouseEnter-Event for the whole window

Tags: c#, mouseenter

Is it possible to create a MouseEnter-Event also for the border of the window? I mean also for the minimize and maximize-buttons. Because if I set the Event for my Form1, it works only when i'm inside the Form, but not on the border and the Buttons.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312752/capturing-mouse-keyboard-events-outside-of-form-app-running-in-background may be help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override WndProc in you form and you can detect mousemove

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            // mouse in window or in Border and max, close & min buttons     
            if (m.Msg == 0xa0 || m.Msg == 0x200)
            {
                //Do some thing
            }
        }
```

Comment: Note: my code detect mouse move so if you want just mouse enter you can make a global variable(bool) and play around it to avoid multiple calls

Comment: That's great it open a big range of options

Comment: @HndlCode,Yeah any event on winforms could be traced by overriding WndProc