# Using doubleclick to catch x,y coordinates outside of a form C#

Tags: c#, events, click, mouse, double-click

I'm making a form application in C# and what I need is to able to capture x,y coordinates outside of the form when the user doubleclicks. I have not been able to find anything that can help me. I'm new to C# so I might be looking for the wrong thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312752/capturing-mouse-keyboard-events-outside-of-form-app-running-in-background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) old MSDN blog has sample code for using `WH_MOUSE_LL`, a low-level mouse hook that you can use to capture mouse events in Windows. Mouse hooks do not distinguish double clicks however, you will need to do that yourself. You can use `SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime` and a timer to determine if the click was a double click or not.