# Show location of Pointer

Tags: c#, cursor, mouse

I'm trying to implement a screencast application and i need to show the location of mouse on click.

How can I show the location of the pointer(mouse) like there is default on windows with the CTRL key if you enable that option on (Mouse Properties-> Pointer Options -> Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key)

Is there any good solution rather than just draw a circle on canvas with a storyboard to getting smaller and then disappear ?

Comment: You can make a gif-animation and use it instead of a storyboard.

Comment: my problem isn't the storyboard, but the correct position of the mouse outside of my "window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i did it with that code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class MouseHook
{
    public class MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly MSLLHOOKSTRUCT _hookStruct;

        public MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct)
        {
            _hookStruct = hookStruct;
        }

        public MSLLHOOKSTRUCT HookStruct
        {
            get { return _hookStruct; }
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs> MouseDown = delegate { };
    public static event EventHandler<MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs> MouseUp = delegate { };
    public static event EventHandler<MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs> MouseMove = delegate { };
    public static bool Started { get; set; }

    static MouseHook()
    {
        Started = false;
    }
    public static void Start()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseHook.Start");
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Started = true;
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MouseHook.Stop");
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        Started = false;
        MouseDown = null;
        MouseUp = null;
        MouseMove = null;
    }

    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);

        if (hook == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

        return hook;
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                if(MouseDown!=null)
                    MouseDown(null, new MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs(hookStruct));
            }
            else if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                if (MouseUp != null)
                    MouseUp(null, new MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs(hookStruct));
            }
            else
            {
                if (MouseMove != null)
                    MouseMove(null, new MSLLHOOKSTRUCTEventArgs(hookStruct));
            }

        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE = 7;
    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: i am not doing anything for the pointer, I am drawing an ellipse in canvas around the mouse pointer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mouse location using `Cursor.Position`
Then you can draw your circle around the the cursor location.

So if you need it by a key press like with the ctrl scenario you can bind an event listener for key press or if you need something constant you can set an event listener on the mouse move.

Hope it will help
Liron

Comment: i can get the Cursor.Position only inside my window. I want something different, something to work ouside of my app also.

Comment: take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3312752/3839692)
I think this is what you are looking for.