# How do I make a global mouse move event?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, mouseevent

I made an application in C#.net.
It opens minimized, and I want it to be maximized when someone moves his cursor(mouse) anywhere.
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312799/1849024

Comment: It should be possible by [hooking mouse](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C). Btw, requirement "maximized when someone moves mouse" sounds weird, what is the point of starting it minimized?

Comment: SetCursorPos, but this is pure Windows API...

Comment: @imsome1 thanks...

Comment: @Sinatr i just want it to be hidden until someone moves the cursor.

Comment: @WillyK. thanks :)

Comment: @anyoneWhoisReadingThis above links worked

Comment: Thanks everybody