# How can I capture G-Key input using Logitech G-Key Macro SDK without focus?

Tags: c#, wrapper, logitech-gaming-software

I have implemented a check for G-Keys being pressed in a Windows Forms Application (C#) using the Logitech G-Key Macro SDK. Specifically using a wrapper class and the supplied *LogitechGkeyEnginesWrapper.dll* exactly as it suggests in the documentation (included in the SDK).

This works perfectly when my application has focus, and when any child windows have focus. I can check via a callback or an update call (as suggested in the docs) but neither work when my application *does not have focus*.

I am hoping to capture this input (of the G-Keys only) outside of application focus (global). I do not believe these keys send a scan code and the G-Key Macro SDK is required to get the state of this keyboard/mouse key.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have sent an email to Logitech Dev Support regarding this, but have not received anything back at this time.

Link to Logitech Developers page:
http://gaming.logitech.com/en-au/developers

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312752/capturing-mouse-keyboard-events-outside-of-form-app-running-in-background

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't a normal keyboard key. It doesn't send a scan code and cannot be captured this way (IIRC).

Comment: A workaround for this, is to add your application .exe to the gaming profile in the Logitech Gaming software. 

Eg if you want to give your software access to the G-keys while playing Satisfactory, add your programs exe file to the satisfactory profile. Your program will now get keydown events for G-keys while Satisfactory has focus.

Answer (score 4):

After contacting Logitech G Developer support, they responded with the following:

> You are correct in that the G-keys do not function when the application loses focus. There is currently no way around this, as our design rationale is that a third-party application should not be able to read the keystrokes of the current app in question.

So the scope of G-keys data is, by design, tied to the application in focus.